# How to load multiple files from gcs to bigquery using airflow

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, airflow

I have 2 files named: **order_comments.csv** and **order_users.csv**. I want to load these files from gcs to bigquery using airflow. I tested a file from gcs to bigquery, it worked. Now I want to test with multiple files, but there is an error in destination_project_dataset_table with **invalid table id**. I want table name in bigquery is named as file name in gcs. My code is below:

```
BUCKET_NAME = 'my_bucket'
with DAG(
    'dag_sensor',
    default_args=dict(start_date=dates.days_ago(1)),
    schedule_interval='@daily',
) as dag:
my_bq_result = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
        task_id='write_to_bq',
        bucket=BUCKET_NAME,
        source_objects=["*.csv"],
        source_format='CSV',
        destination_project_dataset_table='project_name.dataset.*',
        skip_leading_rows = 1,
        autodetect=True,
        write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
        create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
        google_cloud_storage_conn_id='google_cloud_default',
        bigquery_conn_id='google_cloud_default',
        allow_jagged_rows=True, #allows for missing values
    )
```

Comment: You can't have two different destination tables in a single task. You should define one task for each with the respective source files.

Comment: I have 2 different sources: order_comments.csv and order_users.csv,  use `source_objects=["*.csv"]` to detect these 2 files in gcs. I want to load to bigquery with 2 tables: order_comments and order_users. Can we define something like `destination_project_dataset_table='project_name.dataset.{}'.format('source_objects')` ?

Comment: No, that won't work. As I mentioned, you cannot write into two different tables from a simple task. You need to use the `GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator` twice. One with `source_objects=[order_users.csv]` and `destination_project_dataset_table='project_name.dataset.order_users.csv' and then another with the respective values for `order_comments`

Comment: Wildcards aren't supported in table_destination and source_objects. So each .csv file is going to a different table in BQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expounding on @itroulli's good point on the comment section that `GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator` should be used twice in this scenario that there are 2 tables with file to be loaded each table, here is a working DAG with correct output:

```py
import os
import airflow
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from pathlib import Path
from airflow import models
from airflow.operators import bash_operator
from airflow.contrib.operators.gcs_to_bq import GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator

BUCKET_NAME = '<bucket_name>'

with models.DAG(
    'dag_sensor',
    default_args=dict(start_date=airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(1)),
    schedule_interval='@daily',
) as dag:
    my_bq_result_comments = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
            task_id='order_comments',
            bucket=BUCKET_NAME,
            source_objects=["order_comments.csv"],
            source_format='CSV',
            destination_project_dataset_table='<project_id>.<dataset>.order_comments',
            skip_leading_rows = 1,
            autodetect=True,
            write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
            create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
            allow_jagged_rows=True, #allows for missing values
        )

    my_bq_result_users = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
            task_id='order_users',
            bucket=BUCKET_NAME,
            source_objects=["order_users.csv"],
            source_format='CSV',
            destination_project_dataset_table='<project_id>.<dataset>.order_users',
            skip_leading_rows = 1,
            autodetect=True,
            write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
            create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
            allow_jagged_rows=True, #allows for missing values
        )

    my_bq_result_comments >> my_bq_result_users
```

Successful run in airflow:

[image]

Loaded in Bigquery:

[image]

[image]

Comment: But if we have 100 files, we need to write 100 times GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator ? Is it possible to use loop ? And how to use it ?

Comment: In the scenario you can put `*` to the file name in `source_objects`. Hence, loading multiple files into a single table. However, this won't work in multiple tables for a single file as explained both in the comment and answer sections.

Comment: But it only works when these files have the same schema, right ?